# Data importer that can handle multiple schemas in one file

Tags: spreadsheet, data-extraction

The company I work for is looking to simplify the process of onboarding new customers; one step we hope to streamline is the process of a new customer providing us with some necessary data about their organization. In order to make it as streamlined as possible we've been looking into existing solutions, such as Flatfile, Dromo, and Osmos, that seem quite capable at handling data exported from a customer's system, highlighting any places where required data is missing, and sending it on to our system in a more standardized form.

The problem is, the data we need from our customers isn't just a single list where every row represents the same thing, there are multiple types of data that we would like to import spread out across different worksheets in a single `.xlsx` file. As far as I've been able to determine, none of the import software I've looked at is capable of handling this type of data; several options will accept the file, but will only ask which worksheet to import from rather than asking which type of data is within each worksheet.

Are there any options that offer the same type of service (i.e. take a spreadsheet in whatever format is convenient for the customer, extract necessary data, then send it to us in a standardized form), but are capable of doing so for multiple worksheets in a single file?